# Transferring VirtualBox Virtual Machines to another computer

Tags: virtualbox, transfer

Is there any way to transfer VirtualBox VMs, with their operating system and all their files intact, to another computer?

Comment: As far as I understood, you want to transfer the *virtual machines*, not the installation of the VirtualBox software. Please correct me if I'm wrong. For the sake completeness you could tell us which operating system you have.

Comment: I have Windows 7 as my host and Ubuntu as the only guest. I will be using a completely different computer but I want to transfer everything I have on Ubuntu with all the files and apps if possible.

Answer (score 12):

[Cloning a VirtualBox VM](http://www.oracledistilled.com/virtualbox/cloning-a-virtualbox-vm/) explains the cloning process on a Windows 7 64bit host cloning an Oracle Linux 5 64bit guest using Virtual Box 4.0, which I believe matches your situation more closely.

You can also take a look a the following articles for reference:

1. [Cloning a Virtual Machine in VirtualBox](http://umairj.com/191/cloning-a-virtual-machine-in-virtualbox/)
2. [Clone a VirtualBox Guest VM](http://www.wiredrevolution.com/virtualbox/clone-a-virtualbox-guest-vm)
3. [Copying a VirtualBox virtual machine onto another host computer](http://jen3ral.wordpress.com/2009/03/02/copying-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine-onto-another-host-computer/).
4. [How to copy and transfer or backup a Virtualbox Virtual Machine .vdi](http://www.my-guides.net/en/guides/general-software/155-how-to-copy-and-transfer-or-backup-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine-vdi).

Comment: Will cloning or copying it preserve all my files and apps in Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes. Its an exact copy of your setup, including files and apps. I have updated the answer with an article more appropriate for your configuration.

Comment: How can I check that it will work properly at other PC? I don't have m y future host PC with me now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand what you're asking...
If you're talking about the app, there isn't a workaround, you must reinstall it. Regarding the VMs, you can simply copy them to a the other computer, look for the directory where they're stored (Look in File->Preferences to find the Default VM Folder).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what Host OS are you running? Did you store all the files and VMs in their default locations? If it's Linux it is easy to switch to another Linux, but moving from/to Windows is a bit involved.

Note that you *must* shut down all the virtual machines, not just sleep them or save their state. You must actually shut them down.

Answer (score 1):

Open Virtual Box, highlight the machine you want to copy, click machine on the menu, click show in explorer , copy the entire VM  folder to an outside drive, transfer the folder to the new machine, open virtual box and click machine , add machine , go to where you transferred the machine to. and open sesame