# VirtualBox Clone VM for another PC

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, clone

Let's assume I have a vm named **Lubuntu.vdi**, **unregistered** to VirtualBox, and it resides on **PC-Private**. Now, I clone the vm and the clone has the name **Public-Lubuntu.vdi**, and it resides on **PC-Private**. Could I still use **Lubuntu.vdi** on PC-Private? Will it cause an error?

Comment: Check this similar thread [VirtualBox Virtual Machines to another computer](http://superuser.com/questions/321510/transferring-virtualbox-virtual-machines-to-another-computer).

Comment: If you clone the vhd then change the guid of the vhd you should not have a problem.

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/633431/whats-the-recommended-way-to-move-a-virtualbox-vm-to-another-computer).